# How to Avoid SubQuery with same output in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good Day!
I already saw other post about avoiding subquery / using JOIN statement, but still I can't figure it out why my query is so very slow to execute the 9 result data. but when the result data is more than thousands the query execute 0.7k ms only.

My question is , how can I speed up this query execution, what will I remove/add, Or do I need to re-construct the query? how?

here's my query

```
SELECT a.ts, b.bc, b.rem, c.dept FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (select doc, max(ID) from table1 Group By doc) d ON d.doc=a.doc AND d.ID=a.ID
INNER JOIN table2 c ON c.u_id=a.u_id
INNER JOIN table3 b ON b.id=a.doc
WHERE c.depart = 'deparment' AND b.end = 0
```

here is the Screen Shot of
[EXPLAIN result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qdoN.png)

Updated SS for [EXPLAIN result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbH8a.png)

I already set INDEX :
ALTER TABLE `table3` ADD INDEX max_id (`end`,`id`,`bc`);
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX max_id (`ID`,`doc`,`u_id`,`ts`,`rem`);
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX m_id (`doc`,`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD INDEX user_max (`dept`,`u_id`);

Answer (score 0):

Try a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.ts, b.bc, b.rem, c.dept
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 c
     ON c.u_id = a.u_id INNER JOIN
     table3 b
     ON b.id  =a.doc
WHERE c.depart = 'deparment' AND b.end = 0 AND
      d.id = (SELECT MAX(t1.id) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.doc = a.doc);
```

For the correlated subquery you want an index on `table1(doc, id)`.

Comment: ohh.. it takes 5 seconds to execute for only 9 data result

Comment: but when 35k+ data , it execute 0.0350 seconds only, it's weird , right?

Comment: please see updated SS for EXPLAIN result using your suggested query

Comment: @koroku . . . Are you complaining that it is fast?

Comment: No,, I am just want to know why if the query result is only few its execution is slow, then if the query result are many like 35k+ data the execution is fast. then why it happen?

Comment: @koroku have a read this [Sql Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/processing-a-sql-statement?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @dwir182 yeah, I almost know that, but I don't really get is, why is that query is so weird. i really don't know why.